# as3 slideshow won't load

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

This problem has been driving me up the wall for months. I can't figure out why my background on my website:

[www.the-ruck.us](http://www.the-ruck.us)

Doesn't load properly.

I know the code works, because when I run it on my computer, everything loads fine. However, when I publish it to the web, and browse to my page, the slideshow just stays blank.

Here's the [API](https://www.greensock.com/as/docs/tween/com/greensock/loading/XMLLoader.html) for the XMLLoader class I use

Here's the code:

```
var slideshowXMLLoader:XMLLoader = new XMLLoader("slideshow.xml", {autoDispose:true, onComplete:LoadXML});

slideshowXMLLoader.load();

function LoadXML(e:Event) {
        slideshowXML = new XML(e.target.content);
        parse(slideshowXML);
}

function parse(ssXML:XML) { wallpaperLinks = slideshowXML.img.attributes(); }

function loadFirstPaper() {
    ticker.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, changePaper);
    TweenMax.to(landing, .5, {alpha:0, ease:Quint.easeOut});
    TweenMax.to(bloomer, 1, {alpha:0, ease:Quint.easeOut});
    loadWallpaper(randomNumber());
}

function loadWallpaper(i:Number) {
    paperCounter = i;
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(wallpaperLinks[paperCounter]);
    loader.load(req);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fadeIn);
    }

function fadeIn(e:Event) { 
    if (!isPaused) ticker.start();
    var temp = e.target.content;
    wallpaper.addChild(temp);
    TweenMax.from(temp, fadeTime, {alpha:0, ease:Quint.easeOut});
    }

function changePaper(e:Event) {
    ticker.stop();
    loadWallpaper(randomNumber());
    }

function randomNumber():Number
    { return Math.floor(Math.random() * 53); }

}
```

slideshow.xml contains this:

```
<wallpapers>
    <img link="imgs/one.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/two.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/three.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/four.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/five.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/six.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/seven.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/eight.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/nine.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/ten.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/eleven.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/twelve.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/thirteen.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fourteen.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fifteen.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/sixteen.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/seventeen.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/eighteen.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/nineteen.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/twenty.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/twentyone.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/twentytwo.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/twentythree.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/twentyfour.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/twentyfive.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/twentysix.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/twentyseven.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/twentyeight.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/twentynine.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/thirty.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/thirtyone.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/thirtytwo.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/thirtythree.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/thirtyfour.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/thirtyfive.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/thirtysix.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/thirtyseven.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/thirtyeight.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/thirtynine.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fourty.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fourtyone.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fourtytwo.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fourtythree.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fourtyfour.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fourtyfive.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fourtysix.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fourtyseven.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fourtyeight.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fourtynine.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fifty.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fiftyone.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fiftytwo.jpg"></img>
    <img link="imgs/fiftythree.jpg"></img>
</wallpapers>
```

I've tried running Firebug on my site, and, unless I was doing that wrong, too, no errors or warnings came up. So I'm completely stumped. Anybody have any ideas?

Any help is deeply appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what's the value of `wallpaperLinks[paperCounter]` ?

Comment: Where/when is `LoadXML`, `loadFirstPaper` and `loadWallpaper` invoked? It would be useful if you would post the complete code.

Comment: I have often made use of `ExternalInterface.call("console.info", "link = " + wallpaperLinks[paperCounter])` when debugging issues like this where local stuff works, but remote via browser doesn't.

Comment: sow the code that leads up to calling parse()  I bet that's where the issue is.  better yet... loadXML.

Comment: @jidma randomNumber() generates a random value between 1-53 every time the wallpaper changes, and that generated value gets assigned to paperCounter in the loadWallpaper function.
So wallpaperLinks[paperCounter] is one of the links from the XML document I add above.

Comment: @ndm I added all the code where LoadXML, loadFirstPaper and loadWallpaper are called.

Comment: @JasonReeves added the code that leads up to the parse() call and the LoadXML, also the XML source

Answer (score 0):

OK here is what I believe is happening.  I went to your site and it throws a null reference error in loadWallpaper().  This only thing in loadWallpaper() that could be null that I can tell is wallpaperLinks.  wallpaperLinks is set after the XMLLoader has completed it's load.  You didn't show the code that calls loadFirstPaper().  So I bet you have a race condition.  On your computer, the local load of the XML happens faster than online so you don't see it local.

Do this, move you loadFirstPaper call to here:

```
function parse(ssXML:XML) { 
    wallpaperLinks = slideshowXML.img.attributes(); 
    loadFirstPaper();
}
```

Comment: I implemented this change, and it doesn't appear to have resolved the issue. I suspect the problem is in this line:

var slideshowXMLLoader:XMLLoader = new XMLLoader("slideshow.xml", {autoDispose:true, onComplete:LoadXML});
LoadXML is getting called before the XMLLoader constructor is actually done loading. I don't know why, but I've regularly had issues with onComplete events firing before the event is actually complete, which appears to be what's happening here.

Why do onComplete events fire prematurely, and how do I fix it?

Comment: why are you using that XMLLoader class? Which one is it?  Could be the issue

Comment: Because I've used Green Sock's Tweening classes in the past, with good results. Thought their Loader classes would be good, too... and I'm pretty sure they are, I'm certain I'm just doing something wrong, which makes the onComplete events misfire. I fixed the problem, though (see above).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The problem was

```
var slideshowXMLLoader:XMLLoader = new XMLLoader("slideshow.xml", {autoDispose:true, onComplete:LoadXML});
```

Either the XMLLoader wasn't doing it's job at all; or, and I think this is more likely, the onComplete event was firing prematurely. I replaced the above line with:

```
var slideshowXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
slideshowXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadXML);
slideshowXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("slideshow.xml"));
```

It currently appears to be working as intended.

I would still like to know how to make onComplete calls work properly, so if anybody has any advice, I would love to hear it.

Thanks.

Comment: found this in green sock's docs:  "When autoDispose is true, the loader will be disposed immediately after it completes (it calls the dispose() method internally after dispatching its COMPLETE event). This will remove any listeners that were defined in the vars object (like onComplete, onProgress, onError, onInit)."